# Cancel step if validation fails in asp.net wizard

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using asp.net wizard in my project which is new to me. I have validations in one of the steps in my wizard. If the validation fails i should not allow the user to go to next step. And i am using a asp.net button which navigate between the steps in wizard. I would really appreciate if anyone could help me.

Comment: show us the code what you have upto now and where have you been struck so that we can look at your problem and proceed further.

Comment: Here is my Navigation Button event code.

protected void wizNav_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

 if ((wizClaimInfo.ActiveStep).ID == "stepSelectAddresses")
         {
              var master = RetrieveAddressFields(out IsValid, master);
       return;
  }
}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try canceling the Wizard's SideBarButtonClick and NextButtonClick events:

```
 protected void Wizard1_SideBarButtonClick(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
  {
    e.Cancel = !ValidateWizardStep(e.NextStepIndex);
  }

  protected void Wizard1_NextButtonClick(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
  {
    e.Cancel = !ValidateWizardStep(e.NextStepIndex);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mr.Ulises. I am using asp.net button not wizard navigation button. So, how can i achieve same with asp.net button.

Comment: where is your button? did you place it in a StepNavigationTemplate? If so, you should be able to add CommandName="MoveNext" or CommandName="MovePrevious" in order to fire the event mentioned above.

Comment: I am using that event for Button which is in Navigation template and also for Link button which is in SideBar Template.

Comment: ok, then add this attribute to your button CommandName="MoveNext", this will make the Wizard fire the events above, which you could handle in order to cancel them.

Comment: When i added CommandName="MoveNext" to my link button i am getting following compiler error. " No overload for 'wizNav_Click" matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'.

Comment: This site may be able to clarify this with an example: http://weblogs.asp.net/grantbarrington/archive/2009/11/04/adding-changing-amp-finding-buttons-in-the-asp-net-wizard-control.aspx

Comment: I tweaked the code a little bit sent by Ulises and made it work.

Comment: That's great to hear, let us know if this resolves your question.

Answer (score 4):

I tweaked the code a little bit sent by Ulises and made it work.

1. I have added `onNextButtonClick` property for wizard

   ```
   <asp:Wizard ID="wizClaimInfo" runat="server" CssClass="wizard" DisplayCancelButton="True" ActiveStepIndex="0" OnNextButtonClick="wizClaimInfo_NextButtonClick">
   ```
2. In the codebehind added following event

   ```
   protected void wizClaimInfo_NextButtonClick(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e) {

           if (!IsValid)
           {
               e.Cancel = true;
           }

       return;
   }
   ```

and also followed instruction given in below link.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1014412.aspx/2/10

I hope this will help someone in the future, because i spent almost 2 days trying to figure it out. And special thanks to Mr.Ulises.